# Main stream synonym of "clown fiesta" meaning consummate display of ineptitude

Tags: idioms

I seem to remember having read or heard a possibly compound noun describing a hilariously incompetent performance. The context at the time was football (soccer).

Trying to remember what it was I came up with clown fiesta but that appears to be a [rather niche term](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clown%20fiesta) "used by the League of Legends gaming community". (I don't even know league of legends, so I wonder where I picked that one up.)

If the field of inexpertise is specified I think "comedy" as in "comedy defending" (context: football again) can be used but I am looking for a stand-alone term.

Answer (score 2):

The [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/joke) indicates that the informal term **joke** would be appropriate:

> a person or thing that is very bad or silly

There are also various lesser-used terms that contain the f-word.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Joke does indeed kind of work, but I was thinking of something more specific with a similar vibe as clown fiesta only more commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

At least in the UK a term which acquired currency recently is *omnishambles*. According to its [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnishambles) it was the Oxford English Dictionary word of the year for 2012. It does have the advantage that anyone who knows what a shambles is and is familiar with the prefix omni- can immediately grasp what it means.

Comment: It is from that BBC programme I believe.